# Python except TypeError when calling a not collable instance

Tags: python, exception, typeerror, except

I have  a function which accepts either an instance of a class or a class object as   parameter. Depending on wether it got an instance or just the class itself, it should carry out different tasks. My Idea was like this:

```
def foo(self, object):
   try:
       object = object()
       from_object = True
   except TypeError:
       if isinstance(object, BaseObject):
          #object is already an instance
          from_object = False
       else:
          raise TypeError("Not a correct object / instance")

  ...do stuff
```

but when I run this code with for example a string as object instance I still get

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

So the try except clause does not catch it. Any ideas?

Edit:

This was just a MME, my actual method is

```
def convert(self, newunit):
    """Converts a instance of a given unit to a new
    unit. Returns a new instance of the converted unit"""
    try:
        newunit = newunit()
        from_baseunit = True
    except TypeError:
        if isinstance(newunit, BaseUnit):
            from_baseunit = False
        else:
            raise
```

and the full traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
   print(A.convert('str'))
 File "/home/thomas/Projects/Python/Modules/datacont/baseunits.py", line 307, in convert
   newunit = newunit()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: It did catch the exception. But only to have it re-raised as the object (in this case `str`) is not a instance of BaseUnit.

Comment: OMG, you are right... I couldn't see the forest for the trees.